# trying to display textview in fragment

Tags: java, android, textview, fragment

yes I know it has been asked but mine is always null
I tried all ways 
plz help,
the error massage:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView tvInfo;

    public  InfoFragment(){};
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

        tvInfo = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
        tvInfo.setText("hello");

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tvInfo = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_info);

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct layout id?

Comment: check whether the layout is correct.

Comment: I was using the wrong layout.. thank you... embarrassed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you showed is correct. It should be doing it right 100%.
But, maybe you are inflating different layout and that's why TextView is null